# How to use advanced search of Twitter in R

Tags: r, twitter

I want to use the advanced search options from the link `https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en`    to extract the twitter data. 
I want to do this in R. How this can be achieved?

twitteR package allows only `searchTwitter` option. This doesnt support the advanced search.

Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: Check the options of searchTwitter, there are numerous options, including language, time, location and number of tweets. Check https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn - Thanks for reply. I am actually looking for using options such as - "Any of these words", "None of these words" etc. twitteR doesnt provides these options. Hence i wanted to see if any others options can be used to achieve this.

Comment: there is an option in searchTwitter that gives you the search string.   I am not sure if you are familiar with RegEx. take the tweets out that dont want later on using RegEx, but you can include multiple strings using the function and get those tweets.

Comment: Same flexibility is offered in rtweet package. Otherwise, you're left with operating through the browser.